# Passing values from controller in Json format to components

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, json, lightning-design-system

I am getting value in JSON format in a controller function and want to set it to attribute in it's associated component.

**controller function**

```
userFeedItem: function(component, event, helper) {
    var userFeed = component.get("c.getFeedData");
    var groupID = component.get("v.groupattid");
    console.log("GroupID: " + groupID);
    userFeed.setParams({"groupId" : groupID});
    userFeed.setCallback(this,function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
        if(state==="SUCCESS"){
          var jsontext = JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue(),null,4);
         // var jstext = JSON.parse(jsontext);
           //console.log("USERS_BODY:3 " + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue(), null, 4));
    //console.log("USERS_BODY:4 " + jstext);            
    component.set("v.groupatt",jsontext);
        } else {
            console.log('Problem getting feed, response state: ' + state);
        }    
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(userFeed);
}
```

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller ="ChatterFeedController">
     <aura:attribute name = "groupatt" type="Object" /> 
     <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.userFeedItem}" value="{!this}"/> 

     <div class ="slds">
     <!--Page Header-->
     <div class="slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-grid">
        <span class="big">THOR Announcement</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <section class="slds-card__body">
    <div id = "List" class="row">           
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.groupatt}" var="att">
            <span class="slds-truncate">{{display a value from the JSON}}
            </span>
        </aura:iteration> 
     </div> 
     </section>

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. As written, your post does not contain a question. What is the expected versus observed behavior? Do you have any error messages? Have you written any code which you can include? Please **[edit]** your post to be more detailed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have defined an `Object` attribute you need to `set` an object to it from your controller.

Depending on your return value from your Apex controller, you could possibly directly set the value:

```
component.set("v.groupatt",response.getReturnValue());
```

Or if it's a JSON string coming back from the controller, Parse that instead:

```
component.set("v.groupatt",JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue()));
```

Note, I'd probably add a bit more error checking than I have here, but this is just for example purposes.

Do not `JSON.stringify()` anything. You do not want a string.